# If a spell that is junctioned is used, when does the stat become affected

Tags: final-fantasy-8

in Final Fantasy VIII some of the more useful spells have the best boosts/effects when junctioned, however in battle where you would want to use certain heal/positive stat spells or in the Adel battle where using GF's is a bad idea thus kinda forcing you to use Magic you can still use these spells

so i am wondering, when a spell that is junctioned is used, when does the stats become affected, is it during the battle or after, i'm not just talking about base stats but also resistances (ie. using Protect/Shell/Reflect to boost multiple elemental/status resistances)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stats are affected IMMEDIATELY.  (This is a common criticism of the battle system - it encourages you to hoard spells/never cast magic).